# why js can't run method as a function

Tags: javascript, methods

javascript

```js
console.log([1, 2].map([1, 2].indexOf));
```

> error: Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined

but this works

```js
console.log([1, 2].map((x) => [1, 2].indexOf(x)));
```

---

And in python.

```py
print(list(map([1, 2].index, [1, 2])))
```

This works.

So why the first way failed?

Comment: Because the `this` context is lost if you just pass a reference to `indexOf`.

Comment: I bookmarked this question because, ironically, it helps me explain one of Python's design decisions (the need for explicit `self`). That said, the language tags should be used for languages relevant to the code you are actually trying to fix, not for code in other languages that provides a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` requires a `this` value of an array. Passing

```
[1, 2].indexOf
```

is the same as passing `Array.prototype.indexOf`:

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2].indexOf === Array.prototype.indexOf
);
```

A similar one:

```js
'use strict';
class Something {
  prop = 'prop';
  method() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
const s = new Something();
function foo(callback) {
  callback();
}
foo(s.method);
```

Passing it as a callback instead of invoking it normally means that the `this` of the `[1, 2]` gets lost. For similar reasons, the following doesn't log the array:

```js
'use strict';
// just for example, don't do this
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log(this);
}

const arr = [1, 2];
arr.map(arr.foo);
```

To pass a `this` value to `.map` to indicate the calling context of the callback, you need to pass another argument (though this is extremely odd):

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
console.log(arr.map(arr.indexOf, arr));
```

Calling the `indexOf` inline instead of passing it as a callback usually makes more sense.

Comment: So there isn't any way to do [eta-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction) here?

Comment: Never seen that before, but I think the right way to think about it is that the `this` value is another semi-invisible argument whenever a function is called. Given any call of a function, the circumstances of the call also influence what the `this` is inside it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no, not at the moment. There is [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) that will make directly passing methods possible. With it you'd be able to do `[1, 2].map(::[1, 2].indexOf)`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a lot of movement on the proposal.

Comment: Ah, I remember this stuff now. You can also get a passable method with `Array.prototype.indexOf.bind([1,2])`.